# Organizing array of unknown number of constants in all possible ways

Tags: java

What is the best way of looping through an array, ending up organizing it in all possible ways it can be organized in?

Suppose we have an array:

```
{a, b, c, d}
```

What I would like to do with this is organize it like so:

```
{b, a, c, d}
{b, d, c, a}
```

And so forth, looping around creating one array to analyze per looping.

Thank you,

Comment: no @Keiwan he want all possible organizations is about some mathematics and propabilities

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb: Yes, that is called a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Comment: I would have to agree with that myself.. I simply was not aware that was called a permutation. Thank you all for your help!